# How to set filename(some default) of file dialog opened by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can we set Filename  (something as 'books*') of file dialog ,opened by html tag  . This should list all files starting with books.

Comment: As @Pointy mentioned, and only so you have it from multiple sources: __That ain't possible__.

Answer (score 0):

As stated already in the comments, you can't filter using the file name.

If it helps, you can filter by file extension using the [accept](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) attribute.

```
<input type="file" accept=".txt" />
```

Comment: thnks. Is it possible other than html tag, I mean to say any asp.net, mvc control

Comment: No, because the browser needs to provide that functionality and they don't. Best solution I can see is to validate the selection after the fact. Either on form submission or better with a change event handler on the input element.